# replay local commits in bzr

Tags: rebase, bazaar

I work with bazaar binded to the server.

Our bazaar server was down, so I unbound myself with `bzr unbind` and committed locally with `bzr commit`. The server is up again so I used `bzr bind` and now my commits show as pending merge and my commits appear in the local diff.

I would like to push them to the server on the main (only) branch so that the bazaar history looks like the server never had any issue.

When I try `bzr rebase <mybranch>` it says that I have uncommitted changes, 
and with `--pending-merges` it says I have no revision to rebase...

Do you know how can I get back a straight history ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other changes on the master branch, you can simply `bzr push` to the master and then bind again.